# BUTIL -CLONE gives invalid filename error

Tags: pervasive, btrieve

So I have a corrupt .btr file (filename is `FINAN.BTR`) that I'm trying to recover.
This is possible by using the following commands:

```
BUTIL -CLONE CORRUPT.NEW CORRUPT.BTR
BUTIL -COPY CORRUPT.BTR CORRUPT.NEW
REN CORRUPT.BTR CORRUPT.OLD
REN CORRUPT.NEW CORRUPT.BTR
```

However, when I run `BUTIL -CLONE CORRUPT.NEW FINAN.BTR`, I get the following output:

```
BUTIL-14: The file that caused the error is FINAN.BTR.
BUTIL-100: MicroKernel error = 11. The specified filename is invalid.
```

The FINAN.BTR is the corrupt file. The directory of the terminal window is the same directory as the FINAN.BTR file. When I use TAB to autocomplete the filename, it autocomplete FINAN.BTR so the filename and terminal directory are definitely correct.
I'm using Windows 11.

Comment: What happens if you use a fully qualified path (z:\path\finan.btr or \\server\share\path\finan.btr)?   What version of Pervasive PSQL / Actian Zen are you using?

Comment: @mirtheil using a full path also didn't work. I tried both v8.6 and v12. Eventually, it worked when I moved the file to the root of my hard drive (c:\). I was told the butil command doesn't really work well when the file is located in a lot of sub-folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the FINAN.BTR file to the root of my hard drive (c:) and opened a new terminal window at that location which somehow fixed the issue. I don't know why it worked that way since the only difference now is the location of the file and the terminal which were both correct.